# How to achieve Google Play Animation found in app details activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

Last Google Play update appeared with a new animation where the app description slide on top of A big banner.

Any hint how to achieve such animation?

Thank you in advance.

**edit 1:**
In other words, I would like a fragment at bottom to slide on top of another fragment above with different speeds.